# JOIN three tables using one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table that connects three other tables.

Table SPP:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+  
| SPP_Code   |  City         | County 
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Table SPB:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+-------+  
| SPB_code   | SPP_Code      |  Name | Add1     
+------------+---------------+-------+-------+
```

Table VW:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+  
| vw_Code    | customer      |SPB_code|  
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Table Num:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+---------+  
| Num_Jref   | vw_Code       | period|  Amount  
+------------+---------------+-------+---------+
```

I need to find out SPB_code, Name, City, County, ADD1,  total amount between period 2015/01 to 2015/03

I have done this so far but not sure how to connect two of these queries.

Query1:

```
SELECT spb.SPB_code, spb.Name, spb.ADD1, SUM (num.Amount_1) AS   sum_amount_1

FROM SPB spb 
INNER JOIN VW vw
ON spb.SPB_Code = vw.SPB_Code

INNER JOIN Num nm
ON vw.Code = nm.CODE
WHERE   nm.period  >= '201501'
AND     nm.period  <= '201503'
GROUP BY spb.SPB_code, spb.Name, spb.ADD1 ;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT spb.SPB_code, spp.SPP_Code, spp.City, spp.County
from SPB spb 
JOIN  SPP spp   
ON spb.SPB_code =spp.SPP_Code
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `ON vw.Code = nm.CODE` - I think you mean `ON vw.vw_Code = nm.vw_Code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to join all related table base on its foreign key and group all the fields you gonna query, hope this could help to solve your problem.

```
SELECT
spb.SPB_Code, spb.Name, spp.City, spp.Country, spb.Add1
FROM
SPB spb
inner join SPP spp on spp.SPP_Code = spb.SPP_Code
inner join VW vw on vw.SPB_Code = spb.SPB_Code
inner join Num num on num.vw_Code = vw.vw_Code
WHERE
num.period >= '201501'
AND
num.period <= '201503'
GROUP BY 
spb.SPB_Code, spb.Name, spp.City, spp.Country, spb.Add1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the total amount based on the columns you have specified then the below query will work,

```
SELECT spb.SPB_code
,spb.NAME
,spp.City
,spp.County
,spb.ADD1
,SUM(num.Amount_1) AS sum_amount_1
FROM SPB spb
INNER JOIN VW vw
    ON spb.SPB_Code = vw.SPB_Code
INNER JOIN Num nm
    ON vw.vw_Code = nm.vw_CodeCODE
INNER JOIN SPP spp
on spb.SPB_Code = spp.SPP_Code
WHERE nm.period BETWEEN '201501' AND '201503'
GROUP BY spb.SPB_code
    ,spb.NAME
    ,spp.City
    ,spp.County
    ,spb.ADD1;
```